# TypeScript - declare type of a React component class constructor with a certain static method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I got this to work with regular classes, including classes that extend the target class as you can see below:

```
interface ALike {
  a: () => boolean
}

interface ALikeConstructor {
  new (): ALike
  aStatic: () => boolean
}

function acceptsALike(ctr: ALikeConstructor) { }

class A {
  public a() {
      return true;
  }

  public static aStatic(): boolean {
      return true;
  }
}

class AB extends A {
  public b() {
      return true;
  }
}

class ANoStatic {
  public a() {
    return true;
  }
}

acceptsALike(A); // ok
acceptsALike(AB); // ok
acceptsALike(ANoStatic); // ok (error shows)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIBlgGsUG8BQyycAXMgBQCUyAvAHzIBGA9swDYRwj4C%20%20%20oSLEQoM2CAGFmIAM5goAVwRhmUZASIgIAdwqUyYnIWIBlMHDDAEZKrQYt2nbn3wwFIZcGnEESAA5gMoYQ5MpQBpg4UrLySipQ1LjILghscDIyaOrGfgqMbFbEthpEpVAQYApQIMixEADcxi5EufmFchaFcGadCFRkDhxc2aVlFVU1dY1EfClpGWgAQsgQAB6QIAAmmagjyK0FCEzFxqPlldW1ig1NvPyp6TsAcsw9lkclB10nZ%20OXU7cXIh-IFguRUJR6sgAPTQ5DMLD4YEQAJBSIhVCLSEwuEIpG%20FGg9Hgl5vKzY2HwrAUaBQVTIGQAC2Y2hklCAA)

However, for whatever reason it does not work with React components and TypeScript does not give much of an explanation.

```
import React from 'react'

type Props = {
  test: true
}

interface CLike extends React.Component<Props> {
  c(): boolean
}

interface CLikeConstructor {
  new(): CLike
  cStatic(): boolean
}

class C extends React.Component<Props> implements CLike {
  public c() {
    return true;
  }

  public static cStatic() {
    return true;
  }
}

function acceptsCLike(ctr: CLikeConstructor) { }

acceptsCLike(C); // Argument of type 'typeof C' is not assingable to parameter of type 'CLikeConstructor' - no further explanation.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSYBPMJOABRzAGc4BeOAb1LjhiSZgAuXlACuSUgF9ywAHZ8omdLQDCAGWABrWkgAefWQBMWydDAB0K3JFlJ5AHgYRmAPk7c4aABQBKYQCMICAAbVFkpGXkkRWU4dS0kK1kBMQxodx5bAHdfYXjtDzQAZRgUGGBvPzhAkLCI0jRglCYWFTg9A2NEYgsrcAhbBydXOFAwUJA7GFaNbQy4MFF-YIrPX3meIhhRKFkRcQBuD2kPReXVgTLV4tLyyo24LZ29mDEkI55pE8xRWQxgAZwdBoJBgab5JBeDBQPKzRIDFKiNJQHycOAnYGg8FwrwqHwHOAAekJcAAglAAOaiSbyOAQTC8ai0fBUGj0uL4UYsWQQeDNJhyCkoZa0GAQBYoKAoSYKOkM1nMiFJRHIzkAWjgPLgP1gAAtou1dOMULIrgNzHAgA)

I understand that something about React.Component makes it incompatible, but what is it and is there a way to work around it?

Comment: This is because the `new` signatures do not match, as you can see [here](https://tsplay.dev/wERA2N).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your constructor signature (in `CLikeConstructor`) describes a constructor with no arguments. The react class has a constructor with one argument (the props).

You can defined the constructor signature to not care about the number of args:

```
interface CLikeConstructor {
  new(...a: any[]): CLike
  cStatic(): boolean
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSYBPMJOABRzAGc4BeOAb1LjhiSZgAuXlACuSUgF9ywAHZ8omdLQDCAGWABrWkgAefWQBMWydDAB0K3JFlJ5AHgYRmAPk7c4aABQBKYQCMICAAbVFkpGXkkRWU4dS0kK1kBMQxodx5bAHcvczyUYRRZSgBtAF0-OI1tDzQAZRgUGGBvSsCQsIjSNGCUJhYVOD0DY0RiCytwCFsHJ1c4UDBQkDsYAeraLh4wUX9gls9fDJ44IhhRKFkRcQBuD2kPHb2DgSaD+sbm1uOeM4urmBiJB3HjSB6YUSyDDAaZwdBoJBgNbxbReDBQYQoxLTFKiNJQHycOAPeGI5EbLwqHw3OAAelpcAAglAAOaiFbyOAQTC8ai0fBUGjcuL4BYsWQQeB9JhyFkoPa0GAQOBgFBQFArBRcnmC-lYpK4-GigC0cAlcAhsAAFtEhrolkU3tNzHAgA)

You could also make it accept just one param (the props) like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSYBPMJOABRzAGc4BeOAb1LjhiSZgAuXlACuSUgF9ywAHZ8omdLQDCAGWABrWkgAefWQBMWydDAB0K3JFlJ5AHgYRmAPk7c4aABQBKYQCMICAAbVFkpGXkkRWU4dS0kK1kBMQxodx5bAHcvMEYmYRRZSj84jW0PNABlGBQYYG9SwJCwiNI0YJQmFhU4PQNjRGILK3AIWwcnVzhQMFCQOxge8touHjBRf2CGz18MnjgiGFEoWRFxAG4PaQ8NrZ2BOp3q2vrG-Z4jk7OYMSQrnjSG6YUSyDDAcZwdBoJBgJbxbReDBQYQIxLjFKiNJQHycOA3aGw+ErLwqHwXOAAekpcAAglAAOaiBbyOAQTC8ai0fBUGjsuL4GYsWQQeBdJhyBkoLa0GAQOBgFBQFALBRsjm87lopKY7GCgC0cBFcBBsAAFtE+ro5kUnuNzHAgA): `new(props: any): CLike`